# why Im getting "behave is not recognized as an internal or external command" on windows

Tags: python, selenium, cmd, environment-variables, python-behave

I installed python 3.9 selenium and behave
I want to run first feature file but had "behave is not recognized as an internal or external command"

I added C:\ProgramFiles\Python39\Scripts\ and C:\ProgramFiles\Python39\ to environemt var and to system path variables. In cmd when typing python --version I got proper answser.

I dont have any code yet just Scenario in Feature file

Also I dont see Behave configuration template when try to ADD Configuration to run Behave trough Pycharm, so Behave is not installed
Scenario: some scenario
Given ...
When ...
Then ...
when typing behave login.feature got this error

Comment: You need to share some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Documentation](https://pypi.org/project/behave-webdriver/) has a set of usage instructions like:

```
Usage:
Basic usage of this library with behave requires the following steps:
1) import the step implementations
2) set the behave_driver attribute on the behave context in your environment.py file.
3) write your feature file
4) run behave
```

are you sure you did what's mentioned? Please share your code to understand it better.

Comment: no im folowing this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pXF2uIkeCRY&list=PLUDwpEzHYYLsARXz1o3Ldt1FnvRbvlxsS&index=3 there is nothing about env.py yet

Comment: youtube tutorial could be outdated, you need to check the latest documentation patiently. you may have to create env.py. https://behave-webdriver.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html

Answer (score 0):

I deleted python39 and installed 38 now all is working fine